# Create Telerik Hierarchy DataGridView Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, telerik

I'm really new to Telerik template and C#.... I am wondering if is there a way to bind a Hierarchical data in the telerik gridview using linq...

I have found this link and it is very informative.
http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-hierarchical-grid-tutorial-binding-to-hierarchical-data.html

However, I would like to code it manually if possible..

this code only gets the Header... I want to display the Header and Details on the same gridview using hierarchy..

```
 gvStockTransfer.DataSource = _svc.getStockTransfer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it automatically: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-hierarchical-grid-binding-to-hierarchical-data-automatically.html

and here is how to do it programtically: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-hierarchical-grid-binding-to-hierarchical-data-programmatically.html

Comment: hello sir.. I'm using .edmx database... how can I add a datasource from my .edmx database?

Comment: Here is how to bind to EF: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-entity-framework-using-database-first-approach.html

Comment: do I really need to connect the PK and FK of the tables?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you please elaborate. 
Here is also another approach I found: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/binding-radgridview-to-entity-framework-using-code-first-approach

Comment: this is what I did... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817106/telerik-gridview-hierarchy